# How can you call the cucumber 'step' method while using pry-byebug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, pry, byebug

I've got a collision between the `step` 'pseudo function' provided by the byebug debugger (specifically, I'm using pry-byebug), and the `step` function provided by cucumber for running arbitrary cucumber steps.

I've tried to do my step function call with byebug's `eval` function, but this requires quotes to be nested three layers deep, and I haven't found a way to properly escape everything. For example, this doesn't work:

```
eval "step(\"I click on the \"Save order\" form button\")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And no sooner have I typed up this question than I have found my own answer. So it goes!

You can work around the `step` pseudo function with Ruby's internal `send` method, which is available on everything that inherits from object. Within the pry-debug REPL:

```
self.send 'step', 'I click on the "Save order" form button'
```